# def and resolve in the same clojure macro

Tags: clojure, macros

I want to achieve to return a namespace resolved symbol in a macro that has recently defined the symbol itself:

```
(ns my-namespace)

(defmacro def&resolve [a b]
  `(do
     (def ~a 12)
     (def ~b ~(resolve a))))

(def&resolve foo bar)
bar ;=> nil
```

In the example `bar` returns nil. I however, want it to return `my-namespace.foo`. I know this is not working since at the time `resolve` is called, `a` isn't defined yet. I need `a` to be namespace-resolved at macro-expansion time for my use case [1], however.

In the next run I wanted to declare `a` at macro expansion time (does that even make sense?) and, thus, force that it is present in the current ns when calling `resolve`.

```
(defmacro def&resolve [a b]
  (declare a)
  `(do (def ~a 12)
       (def ~b ~(resolve a))))

(def&resolve foo bar)
bar ;=> nil
```

Doesn't work either.

How can I def something and at the very macro expansion namespace resolve it?

---

[1] My use case is the following: I want to define a bundle of functions and add it to the meta information of a def-binding (thus, I need it at macro expansion time). Currently, I only store the symbols, without the namespace the functions were defined in.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ns another-namespace)

(defmacro def&resolve [a b]
  `(do
     (def ~a 12)
     (def ~b (resolve '~a))))

(macroexpand-1 '(def&resolve foo bar))
#=> (do (def foo 12) (def bar (clojure.core/resolve (quote foo))))

(def&resolve foo bar)
bar
#=> #'another-namespace/foo
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `(macroexpand-1 '(def&resolve foo bar)) => (do (def foo 12) (def bar nil))` 
Doesn't seem to work in my test. Moreover, in your output it returns `#'my-namespace/a` instead of `#'my-namespace/foo`.

Comment: sorry my bad, you need to quote the result of course `\`~a`

Comment: regarding your `macroexpand` output thats more like you didn't reload the macro itself

Comment: I guess this is an example of code that you should run in a fresh repl each time started. When run the first time in a repl it returns `nil`, the second time in the same repl it actually returns he desired value. But if we add `(intern (ns-name *ns*) a)` as a first (non-escaped) statement of the macro is works like a charm. If you'd add that to your answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Then we can do another trick and do resolving in a runtime. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

since the var will be def'ed/created at run time, once the macro has finished it's job and gone away, the macro can instead predict what the var will be named and create the symbol directly rather than making a round trip through the namespace and back

Let's do it manually first

```
user> (def foo)
#'user/foo
user> (resolve 'foo)
#'user/foo
```

that looks right, now let's do it by creating the symbol:

```
user> (symbol (str *ns* "/" "foo"))
user/foo
```

and copy that into the macro definition:

```
user> (defmacro def&resolve [a b]
        `(do
           (def ~a 12)
           (def ~b ~(symbol (str *ns* "/" "foo")))))
#'user/def&resolve
```

and test it out

```
user> (def&resolve foo bar)
#'user/bar

user> bar
12
```

This method is preferable to the approach of using `intern` to create the symbol in the namespace using a dummy value, at macro expand time, then `resolve`ing it also at macro expansion time. Resulting in the same value. The advantage of this approach is that it does make resolve work at macro expand time as in your original question

```
user> (do (intern *ns* 'a :dummy-value)
          (resolve 'a))
#'user/a
```

though i recommend going with the symbol generation approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is a very pragmatic approach. I like pragmatic approaches. Does this also work for cljs? I read namespaces behave a little different here, right?

Comment: Ohh I just thought about it. Won't I have the symbol then instead of the Var? In the symbol construction approach.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting of syntax quote helps, with additional quoting of ~a:

```
(defmacro def&resolve
  [a b]
  `(do
     (def ~a 12)
     (def ~b ~`(resolve '~a))))
#'test-project.core/def&resolve

test-project.core=> (macroexpand '(def&resolve foo bar))
(do (def foo 12) (def bar (clojure.core/resolve (quote foo))))

test-project.core=> (def&resolve foo bar)
#'test-project.core/bar

test-project.core=> foo
12

test-project.core=> bar
#'test-project.core/foo
```

If you actually want to get value of foo into the bar, then you have to deref (@) var you get by resolving:

```
(defmacro def&resolve
  [a b]
  `(do
     (def ~a 12)
     (def ~b @~`(resolve '~a))))

test-project.core=> (def&resolve foo bar)
#'test-project.core/bar
test-project.core=> bar
12
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This approach works, but not at macro expansion time, right? If I want it to be added to meta information this wouldn't work I guess.